# Why is an array of length 3 passing an `if(array.length == 6)` test?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a program with two types of shapes: Triangles are represented as an array of three vertices; Quads as an array of six (they are two triangles glued together). In order to determine if I am in a given shape, I need to first check the triangles, then check the quads by checking each of their two triangles.

My issue is that, even when I click on a triangle, the `else if` condition is being met as well. This means I can affect my quads without affecting my triangles (they both move if one is moved, but that is another issue), but rotating a triangle rotates all quads as well.

Here is the code:

```
    for(var i = shapes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        /* Check triangles */
        if( shapes[i].length == 3 &&
            mouseIsInTriangle( mousePos, shapes[i] ) ){
            /* Update flag to reflect the shape that has been clicked in */
            selectedShape = i;
            /* And update theta if necessary */
            if(shift || ctrl) {
                theta[selectedShape] += thetaStep;
            }
        }
        /* Check quads */
        else if(shapes[i].length == 6){
            var triangleA = [shapes[i][0],shapes[i][1],shapes[i][2]];
            var triangleB = [shapes[i][3],shapes[i][4],shapes[i][5]];
            if( (mouseIsInTriangle, mousePos, triangleA) ||
                (mouseIsInTriangle, mousePos, triangleB)){
                // console.log("A");
                // console.log(triangleA);
                // console.log("B");
                // console.log(triangleB);
                /* Update flag to reflect the shape that has been clicked in */
                selectedShape = i;
                /* And update theta if necessary */
                if(shift || ctrl) {
                    theta[selectedShape] += thetaStep;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you take a look at ```shapes``` before running this block?  Are you actually getting what you expect in ```shapes```.  It sounds like you are not and it sounds like the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: @Goblinlord Yes, I logged my shapes to the console and I can see that all triangles are arrays of 3 vertices, quads are arrays of 6 vertices. What is happening is if I select a triangle, I get that triangle (which is correct), but I also select my quads (which is strange because I didn't even click inside one of them)

Comment: Your `if( (mouseIsInTriangle, mousePos, triangleA) ||
            (mouseIsInTriangle, mousePos, triangleB)){` should probably be `if( mouseIsInTriangle( mousePos, triangleA) ||
            mouseIsInTriangle( mousePos, triangleB)){`

Comment: *"even when I click on a triangle, the else if condition is being met as well"* - what do you mean by "as well"? What do you get if you put `console.log(shapes[i].length)` as the first line inside the else if block?

Comment: @nnnnnn When I click on a triangle, my program acknowledges the fact that I clicked in that triangle in a completely correct way. The problem is that it *also* acknowledges that I am in both of my quads (which is incorrect). If I add the log statement you specified I see that the quads are of length 6 (doing similarly for the *if* statement shows that the triangles are length 3)

Comment: @WacławJasper **THAT'S IT**. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: So the log shows that the answer to your question *"Why is WebGL allowing an array of length 3 to pass an `if(array.length == 6)` test?"* is that in fact it isn't allowing that at all? (So yes, the program isn't behaving as desired, but not because of that.)